# проблема с os.environ['']

Tags: python, ос

Код:

```py
ID = os.environ['id']
bot = telebot.TeleBot(os.environ['5346504231:AAG9jFFDfOGR_AN_iEpK7vK2FPKrWLP0_zO'])
adr = ['Тверская улица, дом 13', 'Проспект 60-летия Октября', 'Улица Винокурова', '3-й Голутвинский переулок']
account_sid = os.environ['sid']
auth_token = os.environ['auth']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
SERVICE_TOKEN = os.environ['st']
USER_TOKEN = os.environ['vktoken']
session = vk.Session(access_token=USER_TOKEN)
vkontacte = vk.API(session)
bot.send_message(ID, '!BOT STARTED!') 
print("!BOT STARTED!")
```

Почему-то не работает `os.environ` пробовал так же `os.environ.get` не помогло надеюсь кто-то даст ответ.

Вывод ошибки:

```
  line 9, in <module>
    from VK import a
  File "..\VK.py", line 6, in <module>
    SERVICE_TOKEN = os.environ['st']
                    ~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
  File "<frozen os>", line 678, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'st'
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что у вас в окружении существует переменная `st`?

Comment: почему не работает? Если ошибка, то это еще не значит, что не работает. Иногда ошибкак указывает на то, что как раз все работает. Что вы хотите получить от ``os.environ['st']``?